# Magento 2 Create Module with same frontName as other module?

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.2, routing

I have to extend functionality of Magento_Customer module and new some more controller under `customer/account` like `customer/account/mobileVerification` so my question is, Is okay to have the same frontName `customer` for another Module `Vendor_Customer` in `app/code/Vendor/Customer/etc/frontend/routes.xml`.

Will it create issues ? or is it okay to do so.

Comment: No you can not create like that

Comment: @NileshGosai can you reason why ? as far as working is concern the url is accessible `example.com/customer/account/mobileVerification` from browser.

Comment: I have given the answer please do like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow below steps:

**Step-1:** go to "app" from root directory of Magento 2 and create new directory code. Then create two more directories in app/code, Namespace and Module Name. The final directory will look like this: **app/code/Demo/MobileVerification**

**Demo** as Namespace and **MobileVerification** as module name.

Please find below Steps:

**Step-2:** create "registration.php" file in **app/code/Demo/MobileVerification/** and paste below code into the file:

```
 <?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Demo_MobileVerification',
        __DIR__
    );
```

**Step-3:** create "module.xml" file in app/code/Demo/MobileVerification/etc and paste below code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Demo_MobileVerification" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step-4:**  create "route.xml" file in **app/code/Demo/MobileVerification /etc/frontend** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="mobileverification" frontName="mobileverification">
            <module name="Demo_MobileVerification" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Step-5:**  create "di.xml" file in **app/code/Demo/MobileVerification /etc/frontend** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="mobileverification " xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Demo\MobileVerification\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step-6:**  create "Router.php" file in **app/code/Demo/MobileVerification /Controller** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?php
namespace Demo\MobileVerification\Controller;


class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory
     */
    protected $actionFactory;

    /**
     * Event manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_eventManager;

    /**
     * Config primary
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
     */
    protected $_appState;

    /**
     * Url
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $_url;

    /**
     * Response
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     */
    protected $_response;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    /**
     * Validate and Match MobileVerification Page and modify request
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return bool
     */
     public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
     {
        $url_key = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        if($url_key == "customer/mobileverification/index")
        {
            $request->setModuleName('mobileverification')->setControllerName('index')->setActionName('index');
            $request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\Url::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $url_key);
            return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward');    
        }
        else 
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step-7:**  create "Index.php" file in **app/code/Demo/MobileVerification /Controller/Index** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?php
namespace Demo\MobileVerification\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Mobile Verification'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Step-8:** Block Class (**Demo\MobileVerification\Block\MobileVerification**), Layout xml(**Demo\MobileVerification\view\frontend\layout\mobileverification_index_index.xml**) and template (**Demo\MobileVerification\view\frontend\template**) file as per your requirement.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I want the mobileverification under *customer* frontName. and don't want *mobileverification* to be frontName. the URL structure is important as client want the URL to be very specific. url need to be `example.com/customer/account/mobileVerification`

Comment: Yes using this module you can use 

http://example.com/customer/account/mobileVerification or
http://example.com/customer/index/mobileVerification etc


I have created Router.php for this. Kindly Check the code 
I am using this kind of functionality in my live website

Answer (score 3):

I think [Nilesh Gosai](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/39472/nilesh-gosai) answer is over engineering in this case.

You can easily create file:

**{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standart">
        <route id="customer" frontName="customer">
            <module name="{VendorName}_{ModuleName}" before="Magento_Customer" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

And your controller:
**{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/Controller/Adminhtml/Account/MobileVerification.php**

And get access by url http://example.com/customer/account/mobileVerification

See in documentation:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/routing.html#before-and-after-parameters