# Magento 2 can I have 2 front names for a module?

Tags: magento2, module, url, routing

I want to create a module for which I would like 2 frontName is it possible. if yes how can I do it ?

Example

```
1. example.com/a/index/test 
2. example.com/b/index/test 
both pointing to app/code/Vendor/Test/Controller/Index/Test.php
```

Comment: kindly review below link 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211269/magento-2-create-module-with-same-frontname-as-other-module/211272#211272

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define two routes in routes.xml

```
    <route frontName="name1" id="name1">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
<route frontName="name2" id="name2">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
```

Create different layout file for router

```
For NAME1:view/frontend/layout/name1_index_index.xml
For NAME2:view/frontend/layout/name2_index_index.xml
```